# Function that takes list of functions and returns list from applying each function in turn to argument list?

Tags: scheme

So for example, given

```
(lfmap '(f1 f2 f3) '(a1 a2 a3 a4))
```

it should return something like evaluating the following...

```
(
  (f1(f2(f3(a1))))
  (f1(f2(f3(a2))))
  (f1(f2(f3(a3))))
  (f1(f2(f3(a4))))
)
```

*Note:* the above might not be valid Scheme, but hopefully communicates my intent. So, what's the correct way to do this? I tried the following...

```
(define (lfmap lfunctions lvals)
    (define (_lfmap lfuncs val)
      (if (null? lfuncs) 
      acum 
      (_lfmap (cdr lfuncs) (apply (car lfuncs) val))))
  (map (lambda (x) (_lfmap lfunctions x)) lvals))
```

But it doesn't even run...

Comment: Your first list contains symbols, not functions. You need to write `(list f1 f2 f3)`

Comment: What is `acum`?

Comment: And if `a1`, `a2`, etc. are supposed to be variables, you need to use `(list a1 a2 a3 a4)` to get their values.

Comment: Are you sure you want `(f3(a1))` rather than `(f3 a1)`?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the standard `MAP` function if you just compose the functions together instead of making them into a list:

```
(map (compose f1 f2 f3) (list a1 a2 a3 a4))
```

So you can define your function like this:

```
(define (lfmap lfunctions lvals)
   (map (apply compose lfunctions) lvals))
```

To define the `compose` function just use recursion on the list of functions with the identity function `(lambda (x) x)` as the result for the base case.